# Why NaCL does not provide anonymous public key cryptography?

Tags: libsodium

At the same time Sodium provides API for anonymous encryption without using ephemeral keys.
Is it a bad practice to just use other user public key to encrypt a message?

Comment: I'm not really clear on the question.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson, from NaCL docs: "NaCl's goal is to provide all of the core operations needed to build higher-level cryptographic tools". Isn't non-authenticated asymmetric encryption, the core operation to build cryptographic tools?
AFAIK, sodium server the same purpose and provides this.

Comment: How is `crypto_box` with an ephemeral key not unauthenticated?  Or do you mean not count hybrid operations, so you can't count most DH-only ECC schemes?

Comment: Crypto_box with an ephemeral key is authenticated. But sodium provides `int crypto_box_seal(unsigned char *c, const unsigned char *m,
                    unsigned long long mlen, const unsigned char *pk)` which does not require secret key for encryption.

Comment: You can't actually authenticate an ephemeral key sort of by definition, so I guess we aren't in agreement on some basic terminology.  Notice `crypto_box_seal` is exactly an ephemeral key and `crypto_box` with a little extra trick to compute the nonce in a space-saving way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I now understand the question: why doesn't NaCL provide a primitive for unauthenticated encryption, making ciphertext blobs that are only decrypt-able by a receiver identified by their public key?  Note libsodium provides `crypto_box_seal` which does exactly this and NaCL claims to (try to) provide all necessary crypto primitives.

In answer, notice `crypto_box_seal` can be built using other primitives.  Sodium says of `crypto_box_seal`:

```
ephemeral_pk ‖ box( m, recipient_pk, ephemeral_sk
                  , nonce=blake2b(ephemeral_pk ‖ recipient_pk))
```

So what we have in terms of NaCL prims are (pseudo-code):

```
sk = random();
ephemeral_pk = crypto_box_keypair(sk);
nonce = sha512(ephemeral_pk || recipient_pk); // NaCL uses SHA512 not Blake2b.
ct = ephemeral_pk || crypto_box(m, recipient_pk, sk, nonce);
```

This can be considered anonymous because the ephemeral key pairs used are not associated with any identity - the secret key should be destroyed immediately after computing the ciphertext message, `ct`.