# How could you disclose what you like and have someone respond with what you want without revealing who you are?

Tags: anonymity

Bob likes Apples and Oranges (virtual, not physical). Alice and Eve are fruit sellers (again, virtual, not physical). Bob wants to indicate his appetite to buy one Apple and one Orange without revealing who he is. Alice and Eve want to sell to Bob but they can't know Bob's identity. How does Bob communicate his preference to buy, and then take receipt, without Alice and Eve ever knowing who he is and without using a central authority?

Comment: "Bob shares what he likes with Alice" needs a definition. It's not even clear if that's information (as in _Bob communicates to Alice the information that he likes 42_) or something physical (as in _Bob likes cake and shares a cake with Alice_). Assuming the former, it's not clear how Bob knows about Alice in the first place; If he cares that Eve knows he likes 42; what kind of communication can occur between Bob and Alice; if Eve is able to replace 42 with 43.. For this and many other reasons that do not fit, the question is not precise enough. It must be improved, or will get closed.

Comment: Are you referring to the [Soviet Spy Game](https://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=2091#comment-329963), or something adjacent to it? Perhaps like a zero-knowledge proof-of-not-cheating for [Go Fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_Fish)?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question. Is it now more clear?

Comment: Is the problem Bob's anonymity, or Alice's identity? My answer covers the first question (as stated in the title), but [What does it even *mean* to be "Alice, the fruit seller"?] is a perennial and eternal question at the scope of the internet elders and other zany projects

Comment: First and foremost, thank you very much JamesTheAwesomeDude for your answer. Can you possibly suggest additional reading material, or topic titles? I am keen to learn more. I don't really know how to search for answers to my problem. Does it fit within a particular sub-field of cryptography?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob

Comment: A stupid solution, get Derek (D), a trusted fourth party. D will know identity of all 3, but will not reveal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Bob needs is to generate an [Ephemeral key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_key): just make (say) an RSA key, use it to initiate and proceed with communications with Alice, then delete it when he's done, taking care never to use it to process any personally-identifying information.

In fact, this is what web browsers do every time you connect to a website: by default, *only* the server has a certificate anchoring its identity; clients are anonymous *until or unless* they supply authentication. Your queries to, say, Searx are confidential, known only by the host and the anonymous client which started that TLS session.

(The bit about "no central authority certifying Alice" is a massive, separate question -- it is the puzzle which X.509, DANE, and an entire *host* of decentralized proto-solutions are still struggling to solve to this day; but I'll include a proto-solution to it as well.)

With any public-key cryptosystem, it's trivial to implement an ephemeral or "anonymous" key, by simply *not attaching identity attestations* to a freshly-generated public key and then throwing it away afterwards; if you're only concerned with the authenticity of one party (Alice is a recognized fruit seller or someone whom Bob otherwise knows the public key of; Bob is an anonymous client with no identity persisting beyond the scope of a single discussion session), it's quite easy -- For example (all messages listed are both signed by the sending key and encrypted by the receiving key):

```
Bob: (Acquires Alice's putative pk_A)
Bob: (Generates a keypair sk_B, pk_B)
Bob -> Alice (sk_B -> pk_A): "Buying oranges for 3 bitcoin, reply-to [pk_B]"
Alice -> Bob (sk_A -> pk_B): [initiate zero-knowledge proof of orange possession]
Bob -> Alice (sk_B -> pk_A): [challenge proof]
Alice -> Bob (sk_A -> pk_B): [complete proof]
Alice -> Bob (sk_A -> pk_B): "send 3 bitcoins to [btc_A] if you want them"
Bob -> Alice (sk_B -> pk_A): [transaction]
Alice -> Bob (sk_A -> pk_B): [oranges]
Bob: (deletes sk_B and all trace of pk_B off his computer)
```

In the real-world, something like this happens if you buy something from an online merchant using a burner e-mail (or no e-mail) and either General Delivery or inherently digital data served over the same TLS connection, though without a "proof" of the online merchant's legitimacy (which, again, is a whole separate scope from merely allowing bidirectional secure communications with an anonymous participant).

---

[Note that Bob and Alice are switched from their canonical roles in your question; I have written my answer to reflect that, but, in the future, you should use "Alice" to represent the initiator/sender of communications and Bob as the recipient or secondary participant. Additionally, "Eve" is used to denote the malicious party -- the hacker or "**E**a**ve**sdropper" -- who may be just eavesdropping, or may be launching interactive or invasive MitM attacks; her abilities are generally assumed to comprise control of the network.]

Comment: That is very clear, thank you. And I will be sure to use the correct nomenclature going forward.

Comment: @user13017275 Re your request for further reading: [overview from Linuxjournal](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/understanding-public-key-infrastructure-and-x509-certificates); [limitations from Neil Rickert](https://nwrickert.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/pki-is-broken/); [Christian Mock at CCC 2003](https://www.tahina.priv.at/talks/pki-sucks.pdf); [2 conference talks and a research project from EFF](https://www.eff.org/observatory); [Real-world attack leaked by Christopher Soghoian](https://archive.is/KgOni#selection-2513.25-2513.243)

Comment: Thanks very much.

Comment: See also [answer to “Why NaCL does not provide anonymous public key cryptography?”](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/47992/8287) for earlier examples of this same line of thought